# Time step Error In Multisim Using 555 timer

Tags: 555, multisim

I am trying to simulate a circuit in multisim and I keep running into the following error. (new to multisim) I attached a picture of the circuit and error. Any advice on how to fix this?

[image]

The purpose of the project is to activate the green LED (left) for 12 seconds when the buttons in series on the left are pressed simultaneously. If any of the buttons in parallel on the right are pressed, the red LED should light for 4 seconds and reset the the 555 timer on the left. This was how we thought the circuit should work but we could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the reset pin of A1 connected to the switches J5-J8, then you need to disconnect it from Vcc first.